# How to make dynamic background image size?

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to make height of the section to fit the height of the background with css?

Right now it takes the height of the section content.

CSS:

```
.content-block {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="header-section" class="content-block" style="background: url(./images/bk1.jpg)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, nam error praesentium dolorum quae provident nulla expedita? Libero, quia, perferendis, illo asperiores blanditiis impedit nemo consectetur commodi architecto cumque cupiditate.</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, officia, quasi, minus, quas odio explicabo similique blanditiis odit unde dolores assumenda aut sint incidunt eaque maiores recusandae eum quod voluptate.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You don't want detours à JavaScript? In case you do, create an `Image()`, get its dimension, and then change the height of the `section` tag according to the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X83ex/)

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
}

.content-block {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```